# Google Play app description in different languages

Tags: android, localization, google-play

I published my app over many countries in the world on Google Play. But, the description is in English(default) only.

How i can manage to give descriptions for different countries in their local language, like user from Turkish store will see it in Turkish language i have provided? We can localize the app itself with `res>values-(en,tr,fr etc.)` within string files. How about Google Play?

By this, i would like to use the advantages of local search optimizations and better understanding of the application in particular countries. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the developer console, at the top of the screen where you fill the descriptions/images, you have a button to add translation.

You can even upload different images per language !

Comment: I think this is what i want, yes! Then this will go to only selected country`s Play store, not public, isnt it? Btw, i can/will accept this as answer after 10 min. Thanks.

Comment: You don't really choose country but languages. Then, yes, people will only see the content in their language, or the default one (which you can also change but I guess English is fine).